# Was there a specific being the "Lord of the Flies" was based on?

Tags: william-golding, lord-of-the-flies

The *Lord of The Flies* character might very well be one of the most famous religious figure in literature. Is there any being specifically that the creature was based on?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

"Lord of the Flies" is a direct reference to [Beelzebub](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beelzebub) (from the Hebrew *ba'al z'vuv*, בעל זבוב, literally "lord of flies.")

Beelzebub is well known as a dark god, a demon, or another name for Satan himself. The clear implication, in the context of the book, is that humanity -- freed of restraints, left to its own devices -- will naturally tend to cruel and hellish behavior; that people are devils, if given the chance.